# Duplicate Document URI in MarkLogic

Tags: duplicates, document, marklogic

I have a duplicate document URI in our MarkLogic database which causes queries to fail so I just want to delete it. So...

```
xquery version '1.0-ml';

xdmp:document-delete("the doc uri")
```

but this gives

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-DBDUPURI: xdmp:document-delete("*the doc uri*") -- URI *the doc uri* found in forests forest01 and forest02

Anyone any ideas on how to delete this document?

(I've tried disabling one of the forests but that doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious to learn how you were able to create two docs with the same uri, that is not something you can achieve normally. I have seen something like that only once in the past years. It might be still listed on http://marklogic.markmail.org/ though couldn't find it myself.

Instead of disabling the Forests, you perhaps should disconnect them. First forest01, reconnect it, and then disconnect forest02. Go to the Forests overview page in the Admin interface, and simply select a different or no database from the appropriate dropdown.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not sure how we got duplicate URIs (I read that it can happen here http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/hadoop/javadoc/com/marklogic/mapreduce/MarkLogicConstants.html but we're not using mapreduce!)

Comment: I did as you suggested (i.e. disconnected the forest) but the query run via cq hung, so I created a temp database with a temp app and attached the forest to the temp database, it then worked fine. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: This is good advice.  Duplicate URIs may be indicative of a bug, depending on what you are doing.  If you can, please report the issue to support@marklogic.com

Comment: @grtjn: i was playing with mlcp where i found fastload option, that enables ingestion of documents with duplicate/same uri !!!

Comment: fastload option of MLCP can indeed cause this. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888962/why-there-are-2-documents-on-the-same-uri

Answer (score 0):

Error:
XDMP-DBDUPURI: fn:doc("/test.xml") -- URI /test.xml found in forests FOREST-1 and FOREST-2 with ts=14545

Answer:
We can't delete it directly using just xdmp:document-delete() which throws this XDMP-DBDUPURI error again.
To Resolve it, please delete it from one forest using the following query. Hope this helps!
[image]