# Why are there 2 documents on the same URI?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm wondering why this has happened. May I know what all scenario's might have lead to this situation?

Answer (score 7):

It is not usual for this to happen. It usually involves document insertions into explicit forests, or by re-attaching forests with documents at uris that are already in use. Fast-loading options of MLCP and the MapReduce connector can have that effect too. MLCP prints a warning for that reason.

Avoid insertion into explicit forests, and use fast-loading options with care.

For more details on how this can happen, and how to recover from such a situation, please check this article from our Helpdesk Knowledgebase:

https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/22/16/handling-xdmp-dbdupuri-errors

HTH!

Comment: grtjn offered the most likely explanation.  Another possibility is mistaking fragments for documents, you don't mention the evidence you are interpreting.  Fragments associated with documents (properties, 'directory' fragments) and 'orphan' fragments (properties etc with no matching document) can appear in some queries as if there are multiple documents with the same URI.  Another cause can be if you move forests from one DB to another (or detach a forest for a while then add it back).  Moving populated forests needs to be done with care.